# Is there any way to prevent Minecraft from pausing when I use Alt-Tab?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I wanna use Autoclicker to work in the background, but whenever I <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of the game it pauses.

Is there some way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Dont use an autoclicker, it's cheating

Comment: @Aceplante A bold assumption to make: it's not when they're playing solo.

Comment: @Aceplante When they can pause the game, then they are playing single player. There is nothing wrong with cheating in single player. The only game experience single players could possibly ruin is their own.

Answer (score 1):

In the options menu, click "Open To LAN" (if you want to play without cheats, the cheats off option is there), and the game will open a server which runs in the background.
I don't know if this works with an autoclicker but I know I can afk without staying in the MC window.

Comment: But will the game pause or not?

Comment: @Joachim when open to lan the game will not freeze time, as it’s essentially treating your client as any other client that’s just connected to a server.